# how to make a data flow for a fact table in microsoft data tools for visual studio SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I am creating a datawarehouse and I have successfully created data flow tasks for the data marts. I have made the data flow tasks for all the dimensions in these data marts. It was clear and easy to follow from msdn and other articles. 
Now I want to create the data flow task for the fact tables of these data marts.
For e.g. 
I have a customer table in my source system. Its attributes are CustomerID, name, age, dateJoined, etc. I have made a dimension for it having attributes Customer_Key, CustomerID, name, age, dateJoined, etc. And joined these in data flow task with arrow pointing from source to destination and I have assigned the mappings. Now I am facing problem in creating the fact tables? 
For fact table the created dimensions will be source, but I don't know how to send the keys of dimensions to fact tables i.e. in this case how to send Customer_Key as a foreign key to the table SalesFactTable?

EDIT: How do I make the data flow task for sales fact table using the lookup data flow task?

```
Customer: cid, cname, age, customersince, level
Store: sid, sname, area, city, country
Product: pid, pname, category, amount

CustomerDimension: customer_key, cid, cname, age, customersince, level
StoreDimension: store_key, sid, sname, area, city, country
ProductDimension: product_key, pid, pname, category
TimeDimension: tid, week, month, year

SalesFactTable: customer_key, store_key, product_key, tid, aggregate_of_amount
```

I need help how to make a sample data flow task for fact table when I have created the data flow tasks for dimensions?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've populated your dimensions you will need to use the Lookup data flow task to find each primary key value to add as foreign keys to your fact table. Without knowing your data it's difficult to say what values you'll need in the data flow to use in the lookup, but it should become apparent looking at your data.

Comment: How should I post my data here? Screenshot of tables in designer mode?

Comment: And can you please elaborate how will we use lookup data flow task to find primary key value? and how to add it as foreign key in our fact table?

Comment: Your dimension tables will all have primary keys. For each dimension there will be a combination of fields other than the primary key that define the uniqueness of the row. You need to match against the combination of these keys against the data in your pipe. The lookup should then return the primary key value from the dimension and insert it into a foreign key field in your fact table. You should probably read Ralph Kimball's book before going too far: http://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Complete-Dimensional/dp/0471200247/ref=asap_B000AP5ULY_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1416933938&sr=1-3

Comment: Okay, when I get all the primary keys from these different lookups how should I merge these primary keys and send them as input to the fact table?

Comment: Once you have looked up the pk it will be added to the pipe. You just have to map it to the correct field in your fact table as you populate your facts.

Comment: But fact table will have one input, and I will get 3 or 4 pks from the dimensions, so how do I send these 3, 4 pks to fact table and I am certain that these 3, 4 pks form a valid combination of customer, store, product?

Comment: Each dimension will need to have a separate foreign key field in the fact table. If you have 3 dimensions in your star schema then you would expect to have at least 3 fields on your fact table that map the relationship to each dimension for a given fact. E.g. if you have an Organisation dimension and their sales fact table, you would have a FK_Organisation foreign key field in your sales fact table which showed the relationship to the correct organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Your Data Flow Task will start with an OLE_DB Source task, which will be a query such as

```
SELECT cid,sid,tid,pid,quantity FROM Sales
```

Connect this to a Lookup task. In the Lookup task General settings, set "Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries" to "Ignore failure". In Connection settings, click "use results of SQL query". Your query would be:

```
SELECT customer_key, cid
FROM CustomerDimension
```

In Columns settings, drag a line from the cid column in Available Input Columns to cid column of Available Lookup Columns. Check the box next to customer_key under Available Lookup Columns. Click OK. Then back in the Data Flow, drag another Lookup for StoreDimension and connect to the Customer lookup. Repeat steps. Do the same for ProductDimension and TimeDimension lookups. Connect each to the next. Then connect the last lookup to your OLE_DST destination. You will see in your Destination task the keys will be there. From there you can map them to destination columns.